# Ajax call returning whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have following page with some random tips:  `http://www.javaexperience.com/tips`

I want to display the tips only on the other pages of website so I am making an ajax call and adding whatever returned by the ajax response to a Div's HTML.

The DIV html is:

```
<div id="tips"><div>
```

The ajax call is:

```
jQuery("#tips").load("/tips/");
```

The problem is that the ajax call results in whole page content to be added to div (since the page gets appended to the div, the above jQuery code gets invoked infinitely) where as I want to add only the tips section. Is there any easy way out?

Comment: Making an AJAX request to bring a hole page and then parsing it kinda goes against the whole purpose of AJAX. I'd make a page with only the tips, or even simply a JSON with each tip. Then you can append those with Jquery or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the load method, it'll always download the entire content. You can specify that a certain part of the loaded page be parsed and placed into the calling container.

```
jQuery('#tips').load('url #tip1');
```

Comment: thanks Jay. also is there a way to stop IE caching of ajax request sent using .load. I can see ajaxsetup to stop caching but is it possible for single ajax query only.

Comment: never mind fixed it with following code: `jQuery("#tips").load("/tips/?cachebuster=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001) +" #randomtips");`

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Hey, that's awesome, I'm very new to AJAX and I always used the AJAX call to go to a separate server-side page with no content, save that which I would dynamically plot and subsequently want returned. I didn't know you could parse by the id of the element like that. Thanks for teaching me something!

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
$('#tips').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

More info on load [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)